# Prepare data for correlation matrix

Tags: r

I would like to create and plot a correlation matrix in R.

I have three vectors I create a dataFrame from.
In a 2D-XY-Coordiante-System the vector "index" would be on the x-axis.
And then I have two variables "var1" and "var2" (y-values) and every value with the same vector index belongs to the same index (x) value.

My tries to plot a correlation matrix faliled as I am not able to prepare my data in a proper way.

How can I prepare my data for the follwing correlation plot?

```
                            var2
           900  800  700  600  500  400  300 200  
     900   
     800
     700
     600   filled with pairwise corrleation coefficients 
var1 500
     400
     300
     200
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
 var1 <- c(10,20,3,1,10,4,21,2)
 var2 <-  c(1,44,1,19,19,29,1,3)
 index <- c(200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900)

 df <- data.frame(id = index, y1 = var1, y2=var2)
 M <- cor(df)

 install.packages("corrplot")
 library('corrplot')
 corrplot(M, method = "circle")
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you explain how your attempts failed? was there an error message?

Comment: With the example data the resulting maxtrix should  be a 8 x 8 correlation matrix but it is only 3x3 as id, y1 and y2 are correlated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is what you are looking for.

```
library(tidyr)
library(corrplot)
(df_wide <- df %>% 
  gather(y, y_value, -id) %>% 
  spread(id, y_value))
#   y 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900
#1 y1  10  20   3   1  10   4  21   2
#2 y2   1  44   1  19  19  29   1   3
```

Calculate the correlations and plot.

```
(M <- cor(df_wide[-1]))
#    200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900
#200   1  -1   1  -1  -1  -1   1  -1
#300  -1   1  -1   1   1   1  -1   1
#400   1  -1   1  -1  -1  -1   1  -1
#500  -1   1  -1   1   1   1  -1   1
#600  -1   1  -1   1   1   1  -1   1
#700  -1   1  -1   1   1   1  -1   1
#800   1  -1   1  -1  -1  -1   1  -1
#900  -1   1  -1   1   1   1  -1   1

corrplot(M, method = "circle")
```

[image]